# Criteria api wrong time

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have timestamp(6) column in my database.
Example : "2020-10-01 00:00:00"
By criteria API I made two predicates

```
private static Predicate withInstantGe(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Object> root, Instant date) {
return Optional.ofNullable(date).map(d -> cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Instant>get("date"), d)).orElse(cb.and());
}

private static Predicate withInstantLe(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Object> root, Instant date) {
return Optional.ofNullable(date).map(d -> cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Instant>get("date"), d)).orElse(cb.and());
}
```

But it does not return columns with dates from "2020-10-01 00:00:00" to "2020-10-01 05:00:00"
The difference is 5 hours... and my ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Yekaterinburg", but I don't undersend how it affects on criteria return.

```
Calendar startCalendar = getCalendarFrom(); (method returns Calendar where i setted yead day month etc)
TimeZone sdvsd = startCalendar.getTimeZone();
Instant start = getInstant(startCalendar);

Calendar endCalendar = getCalendarTo();
Instant end = getInstant(endCalendar);

private Instant getInstant(Calendar calendar) {
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(calendar.toInstant(), calendar.getTimeZone().toZoneId());
return zdt.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
}
```

Comment: Семен Немытов - Any update?

Comment: My mistake was that I use ZoneOffset.UTC, and hibernate automatically edit date in my requests, as i can see just add 5 hours. The solution is when you convert LocalDate to Instant, use local offset and hibernate doesn't add hours, like this :  `.toInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset()) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you do not contaminate the clean [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) with error-prone legacy `java.util` date-time API.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        ZonedDateTime zdtStart = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-10-01 00:00:00", formatter)
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Yekaterinburg"));
        System.out.println(zdtStart);

        // Add 5 hours to start date-time
        ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = zdtStart.plusHours(5);
        System.out.println(zdtEnd);

        // In case you need Instant from ZonedDateTime
        Instant start = zdtStart.toInstant();
        Instant end = zdtEnd.toInstant();
        System.out.println(start);
        System.out.println(end);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-01T00:00+05:00[Asia/Yekaterinburg]
2020-10-01T05:00+05:00[Asia/Yekaterinburg]
2020-09-30T19:00:00Z
2020-10-01T00:00:00Z
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

If you are doing it for your Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: My mistake was that I use ZoneOffset.UTC, and hibernate automatically edit date in my requests, as i can see just add 5 hours. The solution is when you convert LocalDate to Instant, use local offset and hibernate doesn't add hours, like this : .toInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset())

Answer (score 0):

I would try to implement it in the following way to be able to abstract from the time zone, which does nothing but complicate:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(Calendar.YEAR,2020);
start.set(Calendar.MONTH,9);
start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
start.set(Calendar.HOUR,0);
start.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
start.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(Calendar.YEAR,2020);
start.set(Calendar.MONTH,9);
start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
start.set(Calendar.HOUR,5);
start.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
start.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
```

And your predicates:

```
cb.and(
    cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"),start.getTime()),
    cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"),end.getTime())
)
```